# Validating Domain For AWS ACM in GoDaddy

Tags: amazon-web-services, validation, dns

I have requested an SSL certificate from AWS and I opted for DNS validation. Now they are asking me to add a CNAME record to validate. They have provided me the following to be used:

```
Name: xxx.example.com.  [Host field on GoDaddy]
Value: xxx.acm-validations.aws. [Points to field on GoDaddy]
Type: CNAME
```

Now whenever I provide this using GoDaddy DNS interface, it throws an error saying for 'Points to' field:

> Enter either @ or a valid host name such as: `subdomain.example.tld`

Did anyone encounter this issue on GoDaddy DNS entries?

Comment: You can view the CNAME page here: https://i.imgur.com/DusNErE.png

Comment: Yes, what do you put in the "Points to" field?

Comment: I am putting xxx.acm-validations.aws. in Points To field as mentioned in my original post.

Comment: Hey, were you able to validate in AWS ACM?

Comment: Yes. I was able to resolve this issue as mentioned under accepted answer when tried without dot in end.

Comment: @MerajRasool is there any way I can contact you directly?

Comment: @AarthTandel You can share your problem here and I can look into it. Not sure about any direct contact policy here so won't be able to comment on it.

Comment: Ok, So inserted the Cname, type, and value. But, it is stuck on validation pending on AWS ACM.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `Host` field should be filled with xxx (your subdomain) and the `Points To` field with xxx.acm-validations.aws (without dot).

Comment: Hello, I am also facing the similar issue. it should be "xxx.acm-validation.aws" correct?

Comment: @AarthTandel yes, should be so.

Comment: @Mahdi My status in aws is stuck on pending validation. I did the same as mentioned.

Comment: @AarthTandel, please ask this in a separate question.

Comment: fwiw - when adding the ACM CNAME via the godaddy Interface, if you set a custom TTL <600, the stays greyed out, amongst other times when inputting data in this `add` entry form.

Comment: Should the `Host` also be without the trailing dot also? `xxx.yourdomain.com` instead of `xxx.yourdomain.com.`

Comment: The `Host` should contain only the `subdomain` part i.e. `xxx`

Answer (score 75):

I would like to share with you how I figured it out.

It may not fit for all but it may help some people.

The steps are:

1. Go to your AWS account.

   Go to **AWS certificate manager** and **Request a public certificate** using **DNS**

After that you will have this screen:
[image]

On the **Domain Name** enter your domain **without www**
For example `example.com` **(NOT `www.example.com`)**

After the above steps you will see this screen:

[image]

**Now you have Name & Value.**

Go to your Godaddy account and select the domain you have entered at the last section.

Go to the DNS section.

Create CNAME record like this:
[image]

Now is the important part...

The Host will receive the AWS certificate manager's Name, BUT **just the prefix**, for example:

AWS name:

```
_904706782abb3d16301321f28db53e03.example.com.
```

You should grab just this `_904706782abb3d16301321f28db53e03` for godaddy's Host name.
For the "points to" (on your GoDaddy account) input, you should grab the value of the AWS certificate manager.
For example:

```
_0ba986089fff81c1b4f395a2ea75f42e.hkvuiqjoua.acm-validations.aws
```

By the way, the value comes with a dot at the end, GoDaddy will remove the dot at the moment you click enter.
for example:

`_0ba986089fff81c1b4f395a2ea75f42e.hkvuiqjoua.acm-validations.aws.` will become to

```
_0ba986089fff81c1b4f395a2ea75f42e.hkvuiqjoua.acm-validations.aws
```

Finally, it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing with details and screenshots

Comment: It worked. Thanks for the detailed steps. Appreciate!

Comment: Big help. +1. Kudos!

Comment: For me, GoDaddy adds `dot` in the end of "Points to" field. Even if I remove the dot, it still adds it forcefully ! Plz Help

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-DNS-validation.html#troubleshooting-DNS-GoDaddy

Seems really need truncate host

Answer (score 20):

For validating a domain name like `example.com` you just write the first part of `xxx1.example.com.` without the domain name and without suffix dot, like this:

```
TYPE: CNAME
NAME: xxx1
VALUE: xxx2.acm-validation.aws
```

For validating `www.example.com` you just write the first part of `xxx3.www.example.com.` without the domain name and without suffix dot, but including `www.`, like this:

```
TYPE: CNAME
NAME: xxx3.www
VALUE: xxx4.acm-validation.aws
```

You can test above configuration after some minutes with:

`dig TXT +short +noshort xxx1.example.com`

`dig TXT +short +noshort xxx2.www.example.com`

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/acm-certificate-pending-validation/

Comment: I tried the xxx3.www and isn't working... I created 2 "domain names" under ACM the first is *.my-domain.com and the second is www.my-domain.com. Your example (the first one) works great with my *.my-domain.com but the second example with the www isn't working with www.my-domain.com. Any ideas why?

Comment: @AdiAzarya were you ever able to figure out the solution on how to get the www. to work?

Comment: Yes, I will write you an answer.

Comment: This worked for me. The problem was I was writing it with "www" on AWS and setting the CNAME record on GoDaddy without the www. Makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

AWS Certificate manager was stuck on pending for me when I configured godaddy. This method worked for me.

```
On AWS when you "request a certificate"
- For domain name enter example.com (www.example.com did not work.)
- click ->next
- select ->DNS validation
- click ->review
- click ->Confirm and request
- before selecting continue, enter information on godaddy.com DNS (below)

My information was similar to:
example.com   _af2e3647196c.example.com. CNAME _15952034958olprtlswtu.acm-validations.aws.

On godaddy.com
- Login to godaddy.com
- In the control panel select ->manage domains
- select the domain name you want to manage ->example.com
- select ->manage DNS (this link was on the bottom of the page)
- select ->Add (this link was on the bottom right of the Records pane)
- enter information
  -- for Type select ->cname
  -- for Host enter: _af2e3647196c
  -- for Points to enter: _15952034958olprtlswtu.acm-validations.aws
  -- click save

- On AWS click ->Continue
Validation was successful in about 2 minutes
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Host` field also needed to be changed to `xxx.` instead of `xxx.example.com.` for AWS to validate it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this document](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/acm-certificate-pending-validation/?nc1=h_ls) to verify your DNS status:

> To confirm that the CNAME record was added to correctly to your DNS configuration, run a command similar to the following:
>
> Note: Replace example-cname.example.com with your ACM CNAME record.

```
Linux and macOS:

dig +short _example-cname.example.com
Windows:

nslookup -type=ns example.com
```

> The command returns the CNAME record’s value in the output if the CNAME record was added to the correct DNS configuration and then propagated successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with 55 ,i tested it. Only difference is now the Godaddy will not remove the dot after aws ,in the record it show _0ba986089fff81c1b4f395a2ea75f42e.hkvuiqjoua.acm-validations.aws.
Then immediately, in ACM it is validated